# How to extend a hash with multiple values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dictionary, hash, hashtable

So I understand that in R, a hash() is similar to a dictionary. I would like to extract specific values from my dataframe and put them in to a hash.
[The componentindex column is were I have my keys and the cluster.index + UniqueFileSourceCounts columns contain my values. So for the same key I have multiple values. e.g: hash {91: [1,15],[22,99] etc..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn2XP.png)

So I would like to create a hash that contains each key, with multiple values. But im not sure how to do that.

```
mini_df <- head(df,10) #using a small df
compID <- unique(mini_df$componentindex) #list with unique keys

h1 <- hash()

for (i in 1:length(mini_df)){
  if(compID == mini_df[i,"componentindex"]){
     
    h1 <- hash(mini_df[i,"componentindex"] ,c(mini_df[i,"cluster.index"],mini_df[i,"UniqueFileSourcesCount"]))
  }
  #h2 <- append(h2,h1)
}
```

if I print h1 , I end up having only the last value:

```
<hash> containing 1 key-value pair(s).
  91 : 42  5
```

Which I understand since I don't append to this hash but overwrite it. Im not sure how to append/expand hashes in R and I have not been able to find a solution yet.

mini_df:

```
                   UniqueFileSourcesCount    cluster.index        componentindex
1                              15                     1                     91
2                              15                    10                     -1
3                              99                    22                     91
4                              63                    23                   1675
5                              12                    25                     91
6                               6                    27                     91
7                              50                    37                     91
8                               5                    42                     91
9                               2                    43                     -1
10                              2                    69                     -1
```

Comment: You should post a reproducible example.  We don't know what package you found `hash()` in, what's in `df`, etc.

Comment: @user2554330 i posted a screenshot of how the data looks but i will add a reproducible example.  hash package: https://github.com/decisionpatterns/r-hash

Comment: Using `dput(mini_df)` is an easy way to include data, or just use a standard dataset like `mtcars`.

Comment: @user2554330 i posted an example of my data. I hope its good like this?

Comment: No, we still can't run your code.  You should post something that we can cut and paste into R and expect to see the same results you saw.  Don't make it harder than necessary to help you.